# Pipe input to dockerized socat run on socket present on docker host

Tags: docker, haproxy, socat

My goal is to query Haproxy Runtime [API](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/2-2r1/api/runtime-api/overview/) using dockerized [socat](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat).

Below command returns empty result (`/var/run/haproxy.stat` is haproxy socket located on the docker host)

```
 echo "-h" | docker run  -a stdin -a stderr alpine/socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.stat
```

I've tried to add haproxy socket via volume, but the result is still empty.

```
echo "-h" | docker run  -a stdin -a stderr  -v /var/run/haproxy.stat:/var/run/haproxy.stat alpine/socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.stat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command that worked is:

`echo "-h" | docker run -i  -a stdin -a stderr -a stdout -v /var/run/haproxy.stat:/var/run/haproxy.stat alpine/socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.stat`

Needed to add `-a stdout` and `-i` to docker run

Following suggestion by **BMitch**" tried below command and it worked as well

`echo "-h" | docker run -i -v /var/run/haproxy.stat:/var/run/haproxy.stat alpine/socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.stat`

Comment: Did you really need `-a ...` for any of it? Or was `-i` enough alone.

Comment: @BMitch indeed, removing all `-a` and leaving `-i` was enough. thanks